# Google Recaptcha using proxy

Tags: proxy, localhost, recaptcha

I want to use google recaptcha on my website but the problem is I am using a proxy server to connect to the internet and bypassing the proxy server for testing my code on localhost.
Is there anyway we can use google recaptcha sitting behind a proxy ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "YourHostName");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", 80);
```